# Adding a dual fuel range

Tags: electrical

GE Cafe series C2S986

The maunfacturer's spec is 30 amps for oven. Want to replace existing  range wire ( old 3 conductor for the mid '80's) on a 50 amp breaker.  What size wire for this new 30 amp "oven" circuit would meet the current code?

Comment: To clarify, there's a 50A breaker there now, and you want to replace it (and the wire) with a 30A breaker?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the existing wiring box? Also, is running a new cable, or a separate ground wire, at all an option?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the breaker to protect the stove. You don't need to change the wire because you can oversize the wire.

Answer (score 0):

To meet current code a 30 amp circuit would require a 10 gauge wire with 2 hots, 1neutral and a ground. I say this because a 30 amp circuit requires #10 wire. If the stove requires 30 amps then you would need to go up 1 size to 8 gauge , 2 hots, 1 neutral and a ground. When I installed a similar setup at my last home I left the larger wiring installed and just changed the breaker and outlet but this was 4 wire.